# Kubernetes: spring cloud gateway not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a spring cloud gateway that works fine in the docker configuration, like this:
(all routes/services except ratings are removed for readability's sake)

```
@Value("${hosts.ratings}")
private String ratingsPath;

@Bean
public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
        .route(r -> r.host("*").and().path("/api/ratings/**")
                .uri(ratingsPath + ":2226/api/ratings/"))
                ...other routes...
        .build();
}
```

This gets it values from the `application.properties` locally, and from an environment variable in docker, like so in the docker-compose:

```
  apigw:
    build: ./Api-Gateway
    container_name: apigw
    links:
      - ratings
      ...
    depends_on:
      - ratings
      ...
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    environment:
      - hosts_ratings=http://ratings
      ...
```

This configuration works just fine. However, when porting this to our kubernetes cluster, all routes get a `404`.
The deployment of our api gateway is as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: apigw
  name: apigw-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apigw
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apigw
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: apigw
        image: redacted
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: hosts_ratings
          value: "ratings-service.default.svc.cluster.local"
        ...
```

With `ratings-service` being our ratings service (that definitely works, because when exposing it directly from its service, it does work), defined like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: ratings-service
  labels:
    app: ratings
spec:
  selector:
    app: ratings
  ports:
    - port: 2226
      targetPort: 2226
```

The service of our api gateway is as follows, using bare metal with an external IP that does work:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: apigw-service
  labels:
    app: apigw
spec:
  selector:
    app: apigw
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  externalIPs:
    - A.B.C.D
```

How I believe it should work is that `ratings-service.default.svc.cluster.local` would get translated to the correct ip, filled in to the `ratingsPath` variable, and the query would succeed, but this is not the case.
Our other services are able to communicate in the same way, but the api gateway does not seem to be able to do that.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you checked `ratings-service` logs to see if it's actually returning the 404, rather than the 404 coming from nginx?

Comment: The ratings-service isn't even called, the problem is that the api gateway can't seem to communicate with the service. The gateway returns the 404.

Comment: So it seems to be a router problem, did you have everything well configured, ports opened & firewall port mapping stuff especially ? If all your services are down on your deployment target, it seems to be the most casual problem, and I would check it first. 404 = not found, so it's a good way to go I think.

Comment: Everything is perfectly configured, when exposing the services directly we can access them.

Comment: Could you please [exec into pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/) from apigw-deployment and try to run command `curl ratings-service.default.svc.cluster.local` or `wget ratings-service.default.svc.cluster.local`? Which docker images are base for apigw and ratings deployments? Which Kubernetes solution are you using - some bare metal or cloud provider solution? Do you have any [CNI plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/)?

Comment: When i curl ratings-service.default.svc.cluster.local:2226/api/ratings, it gives me a 404, saying the path /api/ratings is not found, even though i can publically get the rating if i go to <IP>:2226/api/ratings. How could this be? The apigw can reach ratings, but gets a 404?

Comment: Could you please tell me which base image for Docker image are you using so we will be able to [reproduce the issue locally](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Could you please exec into pod as before and run `curl` command using the ratings service IP address + another test with the IP address of the ratings pod (`kubectl get pods -o wide` to get IP address)? Do you have logs enabled for ratings service? Could you please run `kubectl logs {rating-pod-name}` (if you have multiple replicas in deployment please check for each pod)?

Comment: I tried it again with a different service and it seemed to work. I still have no clue why it failed in the first place to be honest.

Comment: Hi @Raven, if you want to have your issue solved please consider answering my previous questions. You wrote - "I tried it again with a different service and it seemed to work." - what is the difference between new and old service?

Comment: The logs wouldn't tell you much. It seems like the service i was using just straight up didn't work. Must have been a faulty version of the image i was using. So no real problem in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Posting community wiki based on comment for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

---

The issue was a faulty version of the image:

> It seems like the service i was using just straight up didn't work. Must have been a faulty version of the image i was using.

Check also:

- [Access Services Running on Clusters | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/)
- [Service | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)
- [Debug Services | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/)
- [DNS for Services and Pods | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)